# How to configure AbpAutoMapperOptions to expression mapping?

Tags: expression, automapper, abp

I want to configure an abp.io application project to successfully map Expression<Func<TDto, bool>> to Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>
I don't know is that can be done by Volo.Abp.ObjectMapping
I succussed to get mapping work like that

```
var mapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddExpressionMapping();
            cfg.CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>();
        })
);
```

var predicateConverted =mapper.MapExpression <Expression<Func<Category, bool>>>(predicate);

but I think I should but that configuration with

```
public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        Configure<AbpAutoMapperOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AddMaps<TesttApplicationModule>();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the **AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping** package for expression mapping and use the `AddExpressionMapping` method (as you mentioned).

---

You can configure the `AbpAutoMapperOptions` option as follow to enable expression mapping (after adding the related package to your ***.Application** project):

```cs
Configure<AbpAutoMapperOptions>(options =>
{
   //add a new configurators and call the AddExpressionMapping()
   options.Configurators.Add(config =>
   {
       config.MapperConfiguration.AddExpressionMapping();
   });
            
   options.AddMaps<TesttApplicationModule>();
});
```